# Javascript in preamble

Tags: texlive, javascript

For TeX Live 2012 there is the package `insDLJS` that allows you to write a documentwide complex javascriptcode in the header of the document, like (Pseudocode):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{insDLJS}
\begin{insDLJS}[script]{script}{script}
some.javascript.code;
\end{insDLJS}
%
\begin{document}
something that execute javascriptcode and something handelt by javascript
\end{document}
```

Now I-ve installed the new TeX Live 2014 too but, like the `media9` didn't work with the `l3kernel` from 2012 the `insDLJS` does not work with the `l3kernel` from 2014.
Did someone know how i can write a javascript in header to include it with `\input{thejavascriptcode.tex}`? Must not be the `insDLJS`, can be something else too so long I can use `\pushButton` and `\textField` !!!Not `\TextField (capital letter T)`!!!.
Thanks alot for your time

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Show an example that demonstrates your claim that it doesn't work in TL2014/l3kernel - I have no problems with `insdljs 2012/11/10 v2.0l ` in a current texlive and with an experimental `insdljs 2014/07/24 v2.0m` in a current miktex.